# Django form save and update model fields in view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have `SetPasswordForm` that only sets user password

```
class SetPasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(SetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])

        if commit:
            self.user.save(update_fields=['password'])

        return self.user
```

and `User` model that has `activate()` method to make new user activate after setting a password

```
class User(BaseUser):
        activation_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
        activated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def activate(self):
        self.is_active = True
        self.activation_code = None
        self.activated_at = datetime.now()
        self.save(update_fields=['is_active', 'activation_code', 'activated_at'])
```

In view, when user submits a form, It should sets new password and activates user

```
class ActivateUserView(View):
    def post(self, request, activation_code):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(activation_code=activation_code)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Http404()

        form = SetPasswordForm(user=user, data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.activate()

            return render(request, 'users/activate_user_done.html', {'user': user})

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'user': user})
```

Question is I don't know where to call `user.activate()`? 
In form or in view?

I don't think `form.save()` should also calls this method because form will not be reusable in other places.

Answer (score 0):

Call `user.activate` before `form.save` because you only want to save the user if he has activated his account.

Comment: In that case I have two DB update transactions. I want to do it in one.